# Handle (non)existing data

Tags: mysql, performance, replace, insert

I have a table which consists of columns for users, categories and amount.
A user can buy an amount products from each category. I want to store only the very last purchase.

```
User Category Amount
1    100      15
1    103      25
```

Imagine that this user has just bought 30 pieces from 100 or from 110. Either additional category or a new category. This can be handled using following pseudo code:

```
SELECT amount FROM table WHERE user=1 AND category=100
if row exists
   UPDATE table SET amount=30 WHERE user=1 AND category=100
else
   INSERT INTO table (user, category, amount) VALUES(1, 100, 30)
```

The other way to do is, just always deleting the old value (ignoring the error message when not exists( and always inserting a new one.

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE user=1 AND category=100
INSERT INTO table VALUES(1, 100, 30)
```

Which of these patterns is preferred from performance point of view?
Does it matter which PK and FK exists?

Comment: is there a need to check history?

Comment: Seems an odd question - why would you want to lose a trail of user purchases? As is you appear to want to know only the users last purchase?

Comment: There is no need for history. That is handled separately in the billing part of the system. This table is just for the last category for specific advertising.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysql` supports `replace`, so no need of `delete` `insert` or `update`. But this one assumes a unique key or primary key on your table as reference

```
REPLACE 
  INTO yourtable  (user, category, amount) 
  VALUES (1, 100, 30);
```

Comment: I was not aware of this REPLACE statement. Sure sounds promising. Going to try it immediately.

Comment: That _requires_ a `UNIQUE` (or `PRIMARY KEY`) on `(user, category)`.